# How to exclude multiple physicsbody collisionBitMask

Tags: objective-c, collision-detection, physics, skspritenode

I found from other SO' answer that you can exclude collisions btw same type of spritenode's physicsbody, by using ~ in the bitmask like so:

```
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.width/2.0];
    self.minionLife = 1.0;
    self.minionSpeed = 60.0;
    self.minionPath = 0;
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = cat_enemy1;

    // does not collide with itself
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ~cat_enemy1; // here
```

Question is how to add more exclusions to this collisionBitMask?

I tried:

```
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ~cat_enemy1 | ~cat_playerShip; // here
```

But not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to or it and then to negate it …:

```
… = ~(cat_enemy1 | cat_playerShip);
```

… or to and it:

```
… = ~cat_enemy1 & ~cat_playerShip;
```

Comment: You're welcome. It is the same, since `/(a+b)=/a*/b`.